Is it safe/a good idea to give a talk about one's independent research (in math) to people in academia?
I'm an independent reasearcher in mathematics. I do have a professional background, a master degree, but I'm not longer affiliated with an university. I have now proven something, that seems to me as a result, that could be appreciated by professional mathematicians. If that is true, I would like to publish it or even become an independent phd student. I think the best way to go about it would be to show it to interested professionals resp. give a talk, in order to get opinions, assessing my own work better, and in the best case become an independent phd student. What do you think? My main concern is that my result/my ideas might be stolen, if I'm an outsider and only show it to few people, that I don't know. I know it might be a bit paranoid, yet what would be the best way to be "safe", without already writing and publishing a complete preprint?

maybe @DustyDimensions meant self-funded PhD student? A PhD is awarded by a university, so one cannot be independent in the sense of not being affiliated with a university.

It's a thing at least in Germany. There you either do your phd while working at the university, or you work somewhere else and you're connection with the university is only through your advisor, with whom you'd meet up from time to time.

Yes that exists in Germany, but it is not that popular anymore among potential advisors. And you have to be really careful about advisors who are willing to take you. It is basically self-funded on steroids: you have no contact with a department, your only point of contact is the advisor. This has resulted in some failures in quality control, i.e. theses of substandard quality (=plagiarized) passing. It also makes the student extremely susceptible to abuse, as there is no one else in the department who can keep an eye on you.

For advisors a big problem is that very few finish. Doing a PhD is hard enough. Trying to do so without support and structure provided by a department is even harder. So most of the advisor's effort will be wasted on a non-finished PhD project. Advisors don't like to waste their effort, and many thus won't take such students.

A case where this might work is people working in a non-university research organization. It is that organization the support and safety structure normally provided by a (well functioning) department.

Thanks for your perspective! What kind of non-university research organizations are you talking about? How does one find something like that?

The benefit of getting feedback from experts on the topic far outweighs any danger of that your ideas might be stolen, which is in my opinion entirely minimal (in the parts of Western academia that I am familiar with). Unless you settled some major open problem, realistically no-one is going to bother to steal a random run-of-the-mill result. While your result is no doubt very precious to you (because it presumably is your first result!), to other people it is most likely not going to be such a big deal that they would go so far as to steal it from you.

It is actually a good idea to write your idea up first. Not so much because it offers some protection against stealing of the idea, but more because ideas usually sound great in your head or when preparing a presentation, but when writing it down you find that one pesky detail, that you could ignore during the presentation with some strategic hand waving, that will bring down your entire argument. (I speak from experience)
Other than that, if you want to get back into academia, you will have to talk with academics. If you get invited to give such a talk, then that is a great place to start.

And if you do end up giving a talk, having written up the proof carefully should greatly improve the quality of the talk.

Thanks! I do write up my ideas, it's just that I find the process of writing up a completely rigorous paper with all the uninteresting special cases etc. quite arduous, especially when I don't know at all yet how it will be received.

It is all the uninteresting special cases that often house that one pesky detail that brings down your analysis. We are not rigorous because we are masochists (well, at least most of us), but because that rigor prevents us from making a fool of ourselves.
